# Finding a content of a page in cms

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to remove one of the pictures on this page http://www.seobrand.com/online-reputation-thank-you but when I click edit, the cms doesn't show those contents .Why and how to fix it ?
        [image]
        [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your theme is likely using a function like;

```
get_template_part()
```

to render that part of the page. dig into your themes files for page.php and see if you can find a call like that. If you modify the template that corresponds with that call you will be able to see the markup and remove the picture from that content.